# regex find and replace all with capture groups throws E488: Trailing characters

Tags: regular-expression, replace, find

My text file looks like this

```
Lastname, Firstname
Doe, John
```

I'm trying to get it to end like this using find replace regex

```
Firstname Lastname
John Doe
```

This regex throws the error, although using find/replace in atom editor with same pattern works fine.  What am I doing wrong?

```
:s/(\w+),\s(\w+)/$1 $2/:g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
:%s/\(\w\+\),\s\(\w\+\)/\2 \1/g
```

Or for simpler syntax without all the escapes use `\v` for [very-magic](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic) ( thanks to @D.BenKnoble )

```
:%s/\v(\w+),\s(\w+)/\2 \1/g
```

Comment: Could you change `\1 \2` to `\2 \1`? The TO wanted to switch Lastname and Firstname.

Comment: why do I need to escape the `\+`  in vim? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: The escape prevents the + from being interpreted as a literal character. I don't know of any other way to do it.

Comment: @lacostenycoder with the very-magic switch, less needs escaping. I suggest you read `help pattern`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I looked into very-magic but if you could give an example of how I might use it here, that would be a big help

Comment: @lacostenycoder `%s/\v(\w+),\s(\w+)/\2 \1/g` (i think)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble perfect!  So why not always use `\v` ?

Comment: @lacostenycoder /shrug im not sure. Sometimes you dont need it.